# Video.js video play issue in android device angular11

Tags: javascript, angular, video.js

I'm working with angular 11 project. I have integrated videojs library for video playing.
Video is playing fine with web-browser. But not playing in android device.
I have created one example link here for this issue [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jgg6km)

Can anyone one suggest me a solution which can work for android?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a video element, with a HLS source. Android can play HLS natively but not well. As the source is already loaded when Video.js is initialised the source is not reloaded. If you make sure the source is only loaded after initialisation then it will be played with Video.js's http-streaming/MSE instead.

One option is to use a `<video-js>` element instead of `<video>`. Another is to remove the `<source>` and load it with `player.src()` instead.